# Azure Release pipeline's stage does not start from new build artifact

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have an Azure release pipeline where I've updated a stage's pre-deployment condition to be `After release` with `Artifact filters` enabled.

I've setup the Artifact filter to use a tagged build artifact which I've confirmed is present in the build pipeline.

When the build pipeline creates the tagged build artifact I do not see the stage with the associated pre-deployment condition start up.

I did notice that adding in a `Scheduled release trigger` under the Artifact section of the release pipeline will run the stage.

1. Is this the intended behavior where I would need to set a scheduled
   release trigger to start this stage?
2. Is there a way to just start the stage directly after the tagged build artifact has been created?
3. I see that under the pre-deployment conditions for the stage there is also a `Schedule` option there. What is the difference between this schedule option and the one under the `Artifact` section? Would this be used so that you could start the release pipeline on a scheduled time and then only deploy to that stage at a different time?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this the intended behavior where I would need to set a scheduled release trigger to start this stage?
> Is there a way to just start the stage directly after the tagged build artifact has been created?

To create a release every time a new build artifact is available, you should enable the [Continuous deployment triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/triggers?view=azure-devops#continuous-deployment-triggers).
[image]

The Artifact filters under the [Stage triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/triggers?view=azure-devops#stage-triggers) is used to trigger a new deployment based on specific artifacts. For example, the stage is triggered by the Continuous deployment trigger, but it doesn't meet the Artifact filters, so the stage will not run.

[image]

> I see that under the pre-deployment conditions for the stage there is also a Schedule option there. What is the difference between this schedule option and the one under the Artifact section? Would this be used so that you could start the release pipeline on a scheduled time and then only deploy to that stage at a different time?

The [Scheduled release triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/triggers?view=azure-devops#scheduled-release-triggers) under the Artifact section is to trigger a release. The release may contain many stages. The Schedule under the pre-deployment conditions for a stage will only trigger a new deployment to your specified stage.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Seems like setting the Artifact's Continuous Deployment trigger and setting an Artifact filter on the target stage worked as expected.